# Set progressBar visibility from Fragments?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know how I can set eg a progressBar visibility from within several Fragments?

```
class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  public setProgressBar(boolean toggle) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(toggle);
  }
}
```

Now I want to call setProgressBar(true/false) from within MyActivity, but also from any Fragment classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Fragment call `getActivity()`, cast it to `MyActivity` and call `setProgressBar(toggle)`

`((MyActivity) getActivity()).setProgressBar(toggle);`